# Pass ID of parent to new association - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, controller

Trying to pass the ID from the Edit action view

on the form I have

```
   <h1>Editing Video</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<br>
<%= link_to 'New Poster', new_poster_path %> | 
<%= link_to 'Show', @video %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', videos_path %>
```

While the user is on the edit form for video I want them to be able to edit the posters that belong to the video (has_many :posters)

On the Edit action of the video controller I added

```
@poster = Poster.new
```

when the user clicks the new poster link they are directed to the new poster and can upload an image

when I create the record - it doesn't pass the ID of the video.

I have in my model for the posters

```
belongs_to :video
```

so I don't know how I am safely supposed to pass the ID of the video edit I was on to the newly created poster.

table Posters
id
poster_url
video_id <-- this should have the id of the video I was just editing...

Routes:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :posters
      resources :people

      resources :profiles
      devise_for :users

      resources :videos do
        resources :posters
      end

      # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
      # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

      # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
       root 'home#index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with a different method rather than nesting routes.

I pass a parameter in the link down to the form, reference it as the value and it passes through:

```
<%= link_to 'Add poster', new_poster_path(movie: @video.id), class: 'btn' %>
```

on the form page:

```
<%= f.input :video_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: params[:movie]}%>
```

Answer (score 3):

If a poster always belongs to a video, then I'd nest the route. You'd do this in your `config/routes.rb` file, and instead of having:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :videos
end
```

You could do

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :videos do
    resources :posters
  end
end
```

This means that in every controller action for a `Poster`, you'd have access to the parent `Video` object. For example, the `Poster` show action would now be present at the url `/videos/{video_id}/posters/{poster_id}`. I would run `rake routes` after making the change to compare the routes you had before with what you get after nesting.

To sum up how you could change your code around, change `new_poster_path` to `new_video_poster_path( @video.id )`. Then, change the `PostersController` so that the new and create actions looked something like this:

```
def new
  @poster = Poster.new
end

def create
  @video = Video.find( params[:video_id] )
  @poster = @video.posters.new( my_permitted_params )
  ...
end
```

Note that this only works if you're editing a `Video`, since if you were creating it then you'd have no `id` to pass to the route.

Comment: I get what you are suggesting and it should work however I get a "Couldn't find Video with 'id'=" error I've tried passing both "@video" and "@video.id" through the new_video_poster_path with no success. (update Note it does move to the Edit page of the Video) and the path for poster new is videos/14/posters/new

Comment: There must be a syntax issue somewhere. Keep debugging, and if you can't figure it out, post your routes file and relevant code in a gist I can take a look at.

Comment: Oh, and if you used the code I gave, instead of `params[:video_id]`, the "new" route should just use `params[:id]` for the video.

Comment: Yeah I figured :id not :video_id, also my params for poster are    `def poster_params
      params.require(:poster).permit(:image_url, :video_id)
    end` I will post routes in next comment.

Comment: added routes to main post

Comment: I've deleted the saffold - rebuilt it all with the new scaffold of film_poster and I get an error `app/controllers/film_posters_controller.rb:27:in `create'` which is the  `@video = Video.find(params[:id])`